# Using a dynamic set of choices for checkboxGroupInput() in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, checkboxlist

I am making a shiny application and one aspect of the UI function is a checkboxGroupInput where the choices will vary depending on what the input file is. For example, if the input file has four choices, the checkbox will display the four choices. If the input file only has 2 choices, it should only display two choices.

My code is as follows -
UI:

```
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'regionsSelected', label = 'Select regions', 
choices = 'regionNames')
```

Server:

```
output$regionNames <- reactive({
dput(names(as.list(openFile())))
})
```

When I upload the file the choices in the checkboxGroupInput do not change at all, does anyone know why?

Comment: see `?renderUI`

Comment: Great worked perfectly, thanks!